# Binary Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, binary-data, data-storage

How do I store binary data in [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)?

Comment: [storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/)

Comment: @Nevir: What information are you specifically after?  What do you feel is lacking from [@phpguy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17/binary-data-in-mysql#18) and [@Mat's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17/binary-data-in-mysql#26) answers?

Comment: Since I can't post an answer, I guess I will do it here. If you want to store certain binary data, you can create a table, set up a PHP file or script to store it, and write certain binary data in your table and let the script do it's job. Seriously, I don't actually know how to use PHP in other languages...

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The answer by phpguy is correct but I think there is a lot of confusion in the  additional details there.

The basic answer is in a `BLOB` data type / attribute domain. **BLOB** is short for Binary Large Object and that column data type is specific for handling binary data.

See [the relevant manual page for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html).

Answer (score 59):

For a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE binary_data (
    id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    description CHAR(50),
    bin_data LONGBLOB,
    filename CHAR(50),
    filesize CHAR(50),
    filetype CHAR(50)
);
```

Here is a PHP example:

```
<?php
    // store.php3 - by Florian Dittmer <dittmer@gmx.net>
    // Example php script to demonstrate the storing of binary files into
    // an sql database. More information can be found at http://www.phpbuilder.com/
?>

<html>
    <head><title>Store binary data into SQL Database</title></head>

    <body>
        <?php
            // Code that will be executed if the form has been submitted:

            if ($submit) {
                // Connect to the database (you may have to adjust
                // the hostname, username or password).

                mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
                mysql_select_db("binary_data");

                $data = mysql_real_escape_string(fread(fopen($form_data, "r"), filesize($form_data)));

                $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO binary_data (description, bin_data, filename, filesize, filetype) ".
                                    "VALUES ('$form_description', '$data', '$form_data_name', '$form_data_size', '$form_data_type')");

                $id= mysql_insert_id();
                print "<p>This file has the following Database ID: <b>$id</b>";

                mysql_close();
            } else {

                // else show the form to submit new data:
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            File Description:<br>
            <input type="text" name="form_description"  size="40">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
            <br>File to upload/store in database:<br>
            <input type="file" name="form_data"  size="40">
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code looks like PHP3 (or maybe 4), which register_globals enabled. You don't want to run this code, and it will also not work on a semi up to date PHP installation (which is version 5).

Comment: -1 for addslashes() where mysql_real_escape_string() is needed.  Can we please stop giving people code with SQL injection vulnerabilities in it?  (No, addslashes() is NOT good enough.)

Answer (score 43):

I strongly recommend **against** storing binary data in a relational database. Relational databases are designed to work with fixed-size data; that's where their performance strength is: remember [Joel's old article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) on why databases are so fast? because it takes exactly 1 pointer increment to move from a record to another record. If you add BLOB data of undefined and vastly varying size, you'll screw up performance.

Instead, store files in the file system, and store file names in your database.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might be due him implying that you should NEVER do it, as opposed to saying it's a bad idea most of the time.  I agree with him generally, but not in 100% of cases.  

There can be considerations other than performance.  For example I'm working on something now where performance doesn't matter at all.  Other factors such as centralisation, simplicity and backups mean that in this case storing in the database makes sense.  Another common reason is replication.

Comment: BLOB field has a fixed 64 kilobytes size. It is not varying, isn't it?

Comment: 64KB won't fit many files inside - so you'll need to have more than one 64KB block to store the data.

Comment: On the other hand storing data in db is OS independent, which can be nice for weird filenames. db can store multiple files with same filename, the OS cannot. It has no read/write/delete issues. It doesn't need an additional backup system. And, it's not public.
So sometimes it's fast in development. Btw. nobody is forcing you to store everything in the same database, in the end it all ends up on a disk.

Comment: @AlexWeinstein, You are confusing binary data with fixed width data. Binary data can be fixed width as well. And fixed width data is not good for all situations. Indeed, in many situations you would benefit from variable width data: read last paragraph of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: Agree with @Pacerier on this, BINARY(16) is stored fixed. As for BLOB: A BLOB has a fixed width pointer to data stored outside the table. That is unlike varchar or varbinary which store it inline.Searching a blob requires some extra steps, but leave it out of your WHERE clause and it is fine.

Comment: i also think storing files in the filesystem is very broken and non-portable. what if the file gets deleted?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question (question didn't ask for opinions on if it should be done).

Answer (score 23):

While you haven't said what you're storing, and you may have a great reason for doing so, often the answer is 'as a filesystem reference' and the actual data is on the filesystem somewhere.

http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2002/07/11/MySQLtips.html

Answer (score 18):

It depends on the data you wish to store. The above example uses the `LONGBLOB` data type, but you should be aware that there are other binary data types:

`TINYBLOB/BLOB/MEDIUMBLOB/LONGBLOB`
`VARBINARY`
`BINARY`

Each has its use cases. If it is a known (short) length (e.g. packed data), `BINARY` or `VARBINARY` will work most of the time. They have the added benefit of being able to index on them.

Answer (score 15):

While it shouldn't be necessary, you could try `base64` encoding data in and decoding it out. That means the db will just have ascii characters. It will take a bit more space and time, but any issue to do with the binary data will be eliminated.

Answer (score 12):

If the - [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/87385/669677) - BLOB field exists, you can save data this way:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field=X'".bin2hex($bin_data)."' WHERE id=$id");
```

Idea taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2558453/669677).

Answer (score 12):

When I need to store binary data I always use `VARBINARY` format as introduced by [d0nut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499257/d0nut) in one of the previous answers.

You can find documentation at MySQL website under documented topic: [12.4.2 The BINARY and VARBINARY Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html).

If you are asking what are advantages, please read the question: [why-varbinary-instead-of-varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393718/why-varbinary-instead-of-varchar).

Answer (score 11):

The question also arises how to get the data into the BLOB. You can put the data in an INSERT statement, as the PHP example shows (although you should use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) instead of addslashes). If the file exists on the database server, you can also use MySQL's [LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file)

Comment: That link say, that MySQL_real_escape_string is deprecated.