# Why decomposing associative array changes somehow previously stored picture?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's read the image file into varialble picture:

```
$picture = addslashes(fread(fopen($image, "r"), filesize($image)));
```

This $picture you can easy insert into database table with no trouble.

```
*for example*:  INSERT INTO $banners(banner) VALUES( $picture );
```

For some reason lets create an associative array $final:

```
$final["banner"] = $picture;
$final["place"] = something...
```

Later lets decompose $final and insert the obtained values into database:

```
  $fields = "";      $values = "";

  while (list($name, $value) = each( $final ))
  {
        $fields .= "$name, ";
        $values .= "'$value', ";
  }
  // Cut trailing commas
  $values_fields = ereg_replace(", $", "", $values_fields);
  $values = ereg_replace(", $", "", $values);

  // Execute query
  $query = "INSERT INTO banners($values_fields) VALUES($values)";
  $res = mysql_db_query($database, $query) or mysql_die();
```

Now MySQL warns "Something wrong" when comes to insert consecutive $value with $picture into database. Why?

Comment: what's the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't destroy your data. Read it directly and keep the variable clean:

```
$picture = file_get_contents($image);
```

Next, prepare the data for insertion:

```
$final["banner"] = mysqli_real_escape_string($picture);
$final["place"]  = $something;
```

Last, there is no need to loop through your array, since it only contains one record. You don't quote the values, causing an error.

```
$fields = "`" . implode("`, `", array_keys($final)) . "`";
$values = "'" . implode("', '", array_values($final)) . "'";

$query  = "INSERT INTO banners ({$fields}) VALUES ({$values})";
$result = mysqli_query($database, $query) or die(mysqli_error($database));
```

I'm using MySQLi here, since the mysql_* functions are deprecated (as well as ereg_* functions).

Comment: there is no need to loop through your array, since it only contains one record...

Comment: --- I must explain that array will contain many records since it collects a different information not presented here. Therefore it is an associative array. I can pass the trouble by naming the detailed fields, but the good way is to use the generalized names as  $values_fields and $values. (Extra info: I use PHP4.3.9)

Comment: 1. Then you'll have an array with many of these `$final` arrays. Each one has to be treated the same way.

Comment: You don't have `$values_fields`; you mean `$fields`. - [PHP4](http://www.php.net/archive/2007.php#2007-07-13-1) does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted here is exactly the one you are trying to run then please note that you are accumulating field names in `$fields` variable but "cut trailing commas" from `$values_fields` which is at this point empty. Putting empty `$values_fields` into your query might be the cause of mysql error.

Why are you doing `addslashes()`? Try to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead.

Also make sure that the type of the database column where you are trying to put your image into is BLOB or LONGBLOB.

You may find answer to this question [Binary Data in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17/binary-data-in-mysql) relevant.

Comment: Of course instead   $fields .= "$name, ";
should be   $values_fields .= "$name, ";

Comment: I mispelled $fields in the post, but it was placed in the script without the mistake i.e. $values_fields