# way to insert base64(from image) string to mysql table

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have node js server using Mysql. and a client(iphone, android phone) send base64 encoded(from image) string to my server.

in my server, what is best way to insert base64 string to table?

1. just insert origin base64 string to column MEDIUMTEXT.
2. after convert base64 to a blob like this(gist.github.com/fupslot/5015897), insert blob data to column MEDIUMBLOB.

Comment: it depends on other things, like, what do you want to do with it once stored server-side? what do you need most, speed or light weight? etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17/binary-data-in-mysql?

Comment: @Kaddath thank you for answer! i need speed.

Comment: @kubawal thank you for answer! you mean that you recommend way 2?

Comment: Yes. Converting from base64 everytime will result in performance overhead

Comment: @kubawal thank you~~